# Change values of column based on key in another colmun

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a unique `frame` like this:

```
GeneName      position      chromosome
ARS-1155      55562           14
ARS-2131      3132             4
ARS-4412      233              1
ARS-1121      411              5
...
```

And I have a `base` csv with few millions rows looks that:

```
BaseGeneName      base_pos      base_chrom
ARS-1155      5222            5
ARS-1155      5222            5
ARS-1323      32111           5 
ARS-1233      51112           1
ARS-1121      1222            5
...
```

As U can see, the second frame is not unique, and it can contain GenesNames which containers `frame` too. But in the base they can have a different position and chromosome number.

`Base` is just a new GeneBank and I need to upgrade positions from my frame to `Base`.

So if I have a

```
 ARS-1155      55562           14
```

in `frame` it should be changed to

```
ARS-1155      5222            5
```

and will be appended to `UpgradedDF`. If some GeneName is in `frame` but no in `base`  should be moved to `UndefinedDF` with old positions.

I write a for loop with statement. Something like this:
(i don't remember well, writing on phone)

```
listOfGenName = [allGeneNames from df]

for i in len(base):
  a = base.where(base.baseGenName == i.GenName).dropna()
  if a > 0:
    UpgradedDF.append(a)
  else:
    UndefinedDF.append(a)
```

Then I drop duplicates.

But It's too long operation. I mean I added `print(i +"/"+len(base))` and I calculate that this operation will be run for few days!

I tried to merge it, but without success. Can someone give me an advice about that?

EDIT:
Resume:
`UpgradedDF` should be only Genes existing in `frame` and `base`. So if in `frame` is `A` and in `base`, `base[A]` should be move to `UpgradedDF`, if in frame is `A` and in base isn't `A` sholud be moved to undefind. If in `frame` isn't `A` and in `base` is `A` happen nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly...
It sounded like all the `base` that the `GeneName` is in `frame` needs to go into `UpgradedDF`

```
UpgradedDF = base[base.BaseGeneName.isin(frame.GeneName)].drop_duplicates()
```

And all the `frame` that is not in `base` needs to go to `UndefinedDF`

```
UndefinedDF = frame[~frame.GeneName.isin(base.BaseGeneName)]
```

Comment: Hi, thank U for reply. Close. Undefined is good, it will works in my case correctly and thank U. But `UpgradedDF` should be only Genes existing in `frame` and `base`. So if in `frame` is `A` and in `base`, `base[A]` should be move to `UpgradedDF`, if in frame is `A` and in base isn't  - `frame[A]` sholud be moved to undefind. If in `frame` isn't `A` and in `base` is `A` happen nothing.

Comment: Hi Artur. In that case your UpgradeDF code will be very similar to UndefinedDF. Using isin. Let me edit my answer to show you.

Answer (score 2):

We can do the following:

1. drop duplicates in `base`
2. `Left merge` frame with base
3. Replace values from base columns in frame

```
base = base.drop_duplicates()

frame = frame.merge(base, left_on='GeneName', right_on='BaseGeneName', how='left')
frame['position'] = frame['base_pos'].fillna(frame['position'])
frame['chromosome'] = frame['base_chrom'].fillna(frame['chromosome'])

frame = frame.loc[:, :'chromosome']
```

**Output**

```
   GeneName  position  chromosome
0  ARS-1155    5222.0         5.0
1  ARS-2131    3132.0         4.0
2  ARS-4412     233.0         1.0
3  ARS-1121    1222.0         5.0
```